# Select file by filenamepattern

Tags: regex, perl

In my directory I've following filename pattern:

> **1. Pattern**
> 2018_09_01_Filename.java

or

> **2. Pattern**
> kit-deploy-190718_Filename.java

Now I'm trying to select every file in the directory which is matching with the first pattern (the date can be different but it's always **year_month_day**). But I don't get any further.

I've been thinking that I could split the basename from the file so that I get the first ten characters. Then I'll look if this is matching with a pattern.

```
my $filename = basename($file);

my $chars = substr($filename, 0 , 10);

if ($chars =~ m/2000_01_01/) {

    print "match\n";

}
else {
    print "Don't match";
}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a regex that matches your needs, example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $filename = "2018_09_01_Filename.java";


if ($filename =~ m/\D?20\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}\D?/) {
    print "match\n";
}
```

**Explanation**

- `\D?` matches any character that's not a digit

  - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `20` matches the characters 20 literally (case sensitive)
- `\d{2}` matches a digit

  - `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
- `_` matches the character `_` literally
- `\d{2}` matches a digit

  - `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
- `_` matches the character `_` literally
- `\d{2}` matches a digit

  - `{2}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
- `\D?` matches any character that's not a digit

  - `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Check the [*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/nEUSPg/1/)